# Cast created_at to timestamp when building query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a question regarding retrieving DB data.

I have a model `Notification`, it has standard Rails attribute `created_at`. 
As you may know, while being `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object on access, this property really holds super precise value that you can access by casting it `to_i` or even `to_f`

So now I want to write `where` clause to `Notification` model and find notifications that was created after certain time. But since multiple notifications may've been created in the same second, I want more precision in my query, so I'm trying to write clause like this:

```
Notification.where('created_at > ?', timestamp)
```

and it doesen't seem to work.

How do I cast created_at value to be able to compare it with timestamp?

Comment: It doesn't hold a super precise value.  `.to_i` [Returns the value of time as an integer number of seconds since the Epoch](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-to_i).  It is still in seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: what about [to_f](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-to_f) ? Does it hold more precise value?

Comment: That depends on whether your database of choice stores the milliseconds.

Comment: Converting a datetime to a timestamp (or vice versa) doesn't make it more precise,  Ultimately it's the same thing.  Calling to_f on something doesn't make it more precise either.  2.0 is not more precise than 2.  Both are equal to 2.

Comment: I use PosggreSQL, it seem like it has resolution of 1 microsecond for date fields. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html. But I still can't figure out how to query with this precision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp comparison works fine, even on sub-seconds.

Try to experiment:

```
# create two users
u1 = User.create(name:'user1')
u2 = User.create(name:'user2')
d1 = u1.created_at
d2 = u2.created_at

# update d1 so that it's exact second (milliseconds = 0)
# update d2 so that it's exactly d1 + 0.5sec
d1 = d1 - (d1.to_f - d1.to_i)
d2 = d1 + 0.5
u1.created_at = d1
u2.created_at = d2

# now create a timestamp just between d1 and d2
d0 = d1 + 0.25

# those queries now give expectable results
User.where('created_at<?',d0).count # => 1
User.where('created_at>?',d0).count # => 1
```

Be careful though:

```
User.where('created_at=?',d1).count # => 0
User.where('created_at=?',d2).count # => 0
```

but

```
d1 = u1.created_at
User.where('created_at=?',d1).count # => 1
```